# OpenCV - Shape Distance Method

Tags: c++, opencv

Currently I am working on a project of detecting defects of product line by comparing the pictures taken by camera. I tried to use OpenCV to extract the edges of the sample picture and the testing picture. However, I am not sure about the next step of comparison. How should I make a conclusion of ok? What measure should I use to compare the pictures?

What I come up in mind is using square difference of every pixels. However, it depends too much on the static environment. I saw the shape distance and Hausdoff distance provided by opencv. Which one should I use? For shape distance, where could I find the logic or methodology behind it? Thanks !!!

I tried to compare two identical pictures (bmp) (just copied from another). The shape distance calculated by shape distance is not zero .... It makes me difficult to set the threshold of shape distance. For Hausdoff distance, the distance calculated is even larger....

Thank you for your kind attention!!

Comment: Have you tried to use image features and classifiers?

Comment: Sorry, as I am new to Opencv, do you mean the template matching function or Cascade Classifier Training function in Opencv? Would you mind giving me more information of the way of using image features and classifiers? Thanks a lot !!!!

Comment: Yes opencv contains implementation for both template matching and Cascade classifier training. From my own experience I would suggest training a cascade classifier better than using template matching. [See this](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/user_guide/ug_traincascade.html) guide for training a classifier that will generate an XML file that you can use like that one in this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/objdetect/cascade_classifier/cascade_classifier.html)

Comment: Check that [tutorial](http://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/01/26/multi-scale-template-matching-using-python-opencv/) about template matching.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorials !! I will have a try on that !! By the way, if I use template matching function to detect objects, will it be possible for me to set a similarity threshold? For example, in a production line of a factory, there are certain degree of acceptance on the defects of the product depending on the degree of defects. I am wondering if the template matching will find the template even if there is some defects in the corner of the products.

Comment: The only way of using template matching I would see - tell me your plan if you have another idea - is to match the image of the product with different images each representing a state - good, defected level 1, defected level 2 - thenwhat the template matching will give you is a score of how close is that image to the template that you can use to guess which class is it. This score is the similarity score if you wish to name it so. But as you have experienced images often contain noise that will affect your results, you might need to do some preprocessing.

Comment: Oh, that is a good idea. I think i will follow what you suggested. For template, would you suggest me to use the original pictures to compare the full testing picture or a canny-edge of the picture to compare the edge of the testing picture?

For preprocessing of pictures, do you mean guassian filters? In fact, sometimes, I am thinking about how to magnifying the features of the products while minimising the effect of the background as sometimes the edge detected in the background may affect the comparison of pictures. Is there any way of magnifying the features ?

Comment: That really depends on the context of the image. You will have to study your image well and decide what really is the feature in the image/defect. Is it edges or corners or is there a texture/binary pattern. You can also test and try what method will give your the best accuracy.
Gaussian filter can be one, it also depend on the type of noise you have in the images, yes you can actually segment and extract your object from the background but that may require user-input.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, as my testing products are plastic products which have many different kind of forms due to the flexibility of plastic. Therefore, the possibility of defected forms are too much to be used to form all the wrong samples used for template matching. Moreover, for the haar classifier, it seems it would allow larger ranges of products. If I would like to have a more precise allowed difference, like only 1mm difference is allowed, which way of detecting or comparing tool should I use? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: A 1mm level of difference is a **very big** challenge. I am not sure of what can be used.

Comment: I see. Sorry that the tolerance level may be too big but that was just an example. I would like to know how to adjust the tolerance level or testing precision when using classifier. Thanks!!

Comment: You mean how to improve accuracy in classifing?

Comment: Yes, is there any way to improve accuracy

Comment: Of course, but this is very dependent on your case. What accuracy do you have now? and how many images you use for training? what type of classifier? How many classes you want to classify?

Comment: I am planning to use cascade classifier and i only need to classify it as defected or perfect. As the testing product is made of plastic, its defects patterns are not predictable. So, i am thinking if the classifier can help any kinds of defect only if it has some different feature when comparing with sample. I am thinking the feasibility or difficulty of using classifier. For example, as i know, it is widely used in face detection. Maybe it can only detect there is a human inside the picture but may not be exactly me. Or somehow my hairstyle changes or my face gets fatter. Is it detectable?